# How to change the color of selected shape in group in powerpoint using applescript?

Tags: applescript, powerpoint

When i am grouped the n shapes in one group, and selected one shape from group and changed the color, but its changing color of all shapes in that group, how to overcome this jack? ,I need to change the color of that specific shape from that group

Below code changing all shapes color

```
tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    activate

    set theShapeRange to shape range of selection of active window
    set selected to child shape range of selection of active window


    set n to (count shapes of theShapeRange)
    repeat with i from 1 to n
        tell shape i of theShapeRange
            set fore color of fill format of it to {14, 235, 5}
            set back color of fill format of it to {14, 235, 5}
        end tell
    end repeat

end tell
```

Comment: Post your code that you have so far, even if it's changing the color of the whole group.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is not possible with AppleScript.

The `selection` property of PowerPoint (2011) returns the grouped shapes as a single object but there is no information about the selection of a specific shape within the group.

the contents of `child shape range` specifies also the group.

Comment: But we can able color the shape inside group using powerpoint default color scheme. So I think there is a way to do that. I don't know its possible using apple script. Do you know any other method to do this ?

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea…

Comment: Can you ungroup, change colors of individual shapes, and then regroup?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with PowerPoint